# Get data from json and use as a link

Tags: javascript, html

`data.query.results.item[0].link` will return a link. now is there any way to use this as a link inside `<a></a>` tag ?

```
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amaderbarisal.com%2Ffeed%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback?';
$.getJSON(url,function(data){

     data.query.results.item[0].link
    }
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: @Артём Царионов Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a id="somelink" href="#">click here</a>
```

JS:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
   $("#somelink").attr('href', data.query.results.item[0].link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*from%20feed%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amaderbarisal.com%2Ffeed%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback?';
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
  var a = $('<a>').attr('href', data.query.results.item[0].link);
  $('#content').append(a);
}
```

This appends a link to a div with id "content".

Answer (score 0):

Depending if the Anchor already exist or needs to be created you can use:

```
    //already exist
    document.getElementById("somea").href="http://mysite.com";
    document.getElementById("somea").innerHTML="text of the link";

    //create one
    var myA=document.createElement("a");
    myA.innerHTML="text of the link";
    myA.href="http://mysite.com";
    document.getElementById("somediv").appendChild(myA);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're asking to trigger the getJSON with a link or to use the response to build an anchor tag. if you mean the latter you're using jquery, why not just use it to build the link?

```
$('<a>',{
   text: 'Text',
   title: 'Blah',
   href: data.query.results.item[0].link,
   click: nil }
}).appendTo('body');
```

NOTE: The above code is untested.